# Debugging through an extension method

Tags: c#, debugging, extension-methods, visual-studio-debugging

I've created a method in C# that extends the string datatype, creating an additional overload to the Split function so that a text qualifier can be defined.
**Example**
string data is defined as "field 1","field 2","filed 3"

```
string[] splitData = data.Split(',','"')
```

The extension works fine. I can access the method once I reference and use the namespace. However there is an issue in the method I'm trying to debug, but the debugger won't step into the extension method.

**Extension Code**

```
namespace Extensions
{
  public static class StringExtension
  {
    public static string[] Split(this string s, char delimiter, char qualifier)
    {
      // Method does work
    }
  }
}
```

**Code in nUnit Test**

```
string testString = "\"Field 1\",\"Field 2\",\"Field 3\"";
int expectedCount = 3;

// Do Test.
string[] result = testString.Split(',','"');

Assert.AreEqual(expectedCount, result.Length);
```

I can't step into testString.Split(',','"'). It returns a result and intellisense shows the extension method. The debugger just steps over it, as it would for the built in Split method.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact, when you invoke `testString.Split(',','"')` what *actually* gets called is a `public string[] Split(params char[] separator)` overload, not your extension method. This is because instance members, if applicable, *always* take precedence over extension methods.

The only two things you can do are either rename your method or change signature somehow so it's different from various `String.Split` overloads.

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue. I renamed the method SplitWithQualifier and now the debugging works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It should call like `StringExtension.Split(...);` Or try below

[image]

Comment: Then probably the way you calling the static method is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a break point in the extension method; execution will stop there.

There must be another way though, one that is proper and usable.
I haven't found it yet.

Comment: The breakpoint shows as 
   "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document."

The project is set for Debug and I haven't explicitly set it not to build the debug symbols.

Comment: It *would* stop (personal experience) if the method was actually being called - refer to @Anton Gogolev 's answer that was marked as answer.

Answer (score 0):

One can verify code to be called by pressing F12 (go to def) or by looking at Reflector output.  I have asked a linked question about how to do this in VS2010 debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I landed here after having a problem getting VS to break in an extension method, I even restarted in case it was a debugger issue.

Turns out **I had my breakpoint in a different method with the same name**. Don't be like me. Eat healthy and fix your sleep.