# How to verify that a correct BCL method is called

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

In the [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7284147/90475) OP has created a situation where a BCL method was preferred to his extension method.  OP could not verify the method to be called.  How can I do with with Visual Studio debugger?

Note:  I am aware that you could press F12 or you could fire up the Reflector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click the line in the debugger and look at the `Step into specific` menu, which will show you the full name of the method it's executing.